# Getting the character that inside the brackets

Tags: vb.net

This is my string:

```
Dim value as string = "IR_10748(1).jpg"
```

How can I get this number 1 into another variable? I am thinking to use split.
How I can use to get this value in vb.net?

Comment: `split` can be used. You can specify both '(' and ')' as delimiters for splitting the string and then extract the required value.

Comment: thanks for your respond I tried something like that:    Dim ImageName As String = Nothing
            Dim IdentifyPictureIndex As String = Nothing  IdentifyPictureIndex = ImageName.Split("(")(1) + ImageName.Split(")")(1) but its not working I'm getting "1).jpg.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim value as String = "IR_10748(1).jpg"
Dim splitStrings() as String

'Split on either opening or closing parenthesis - 
'This will give 3 strings - "IR_10748","1",".jpg"
splitStrings = value.Split(New String() {"(",")"}, StringSplitOptions.None)

'Parse as integer if required
Dim i as Integer
i = Integer.Parse(splitStrings(1))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NQVC32283)

Comment: It's giving me an error where it's says splitted is it vb.net?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, that should be splitStrings(1)

Answer (score 1):

See [`String.Substring(Integer, Integer)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`String.IndexOf(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim value As String = "IR_10748(1).jpg"
Dim startIndex As Integer = value.IndexOf("(") + 1
Dim length As Integer = value.IndexOf(")") - startIndex
Dim content As String = value.Substring(startIndex, length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions might be cleaner.  This should work:

```
dim Result as string = Regex.Match(value, "(?<=\().*(?=\))").Value
```

It'll extract one or more characters contained between the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the prettiest, but this gets "1" using Remove and Split :

```
Dim value as String = "IR_10748(1).jpg"

Dim num As String = value.Remove(0, value.IndexOf("(") + 1).Split(")")(0)
```

That gives num = "1"

Comment: so now the `dirty code` = not useful? I guess its still up to the asker to pick up his solution. +1 to negate

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number more reliably than using String.Split. You'll want to use `LastIndexOf` to get the final opening parenthesis just in case you have a filename like "a(whatever)(1).ext", and you should inspect the filename without its extension, in case you have a filename like "a(1).(9)":

```
Dim value As String = "IR_10748(1).jpg"
Dim fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(value)
Dim lastOpen = fn.LastIndexOf("(")
If lastOpen >= 0 Then
    Dim length = fn.IndexOf(")", lastOpen + 1) - lastOpen - 1
    If length >= 1 Then
        Dim numAsString = fn.Substring(lastOpen + 1, length)
        Console.WriteLine(numAsString)
    ElseIf length = 0 Then
        ' do something if required
        Console.WriteLine("No number in the parentheses.")
    Else
        ' do something if required
        Console.WriteLine("No closing parenthesis.")
    End If
Else
    ' do something if required
    Console.WriteLine("No opening parenthesis.")
End If
```